# You have Archive::Tar 1.3901, but 1.50 or later is recommended. Please upgrade. issues

Tags: linux, command-line

Hi i am trying to install bugzilla on my mediatemple server, i am totally a novice when i comes to cmmd line so have found a tutorial on-line which was going well till i tried to upgrade the above.

the below is the message i get in the command line and after looking on-line for about an hour i cant seem to find a resolution to the issue. basically i am stuck on where to go now to upgrade what its asking

```
Installing Archive::Tar version 1.76...
Running install for module 'Archive::Tar'
Running make for B/BI/BINGOS/Archive-Tar-1.76.tar.gz
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.62)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v1.42)
Checksum for /root/.cpan/source/authors/id/B/BI/BINGOS/Archive-Tar-1.76.tar.gz ok
CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v1.3901)
You have Archive::Tar 1.3901, but 1.50 or later is recommended. Please upgrade.
Uncompressed /root/.cpan/source/authors/id/B/BI/BINGOS/Archive-Tar-1.76.tar.gz successfully
Using Tar:/bin/tar xvf "Archive-Tar-1.76.tar":
Couldn't untar Archive-Tar-1.76.tar
CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.22)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.110930001)
CPAN: Time::HiRes loaded ok (v1.9717)
Package seems to come without Makefile.PL.
  (The test -f "/root/.cpan/build/BINGOS-J_TqCf/Makefile.PL" returned false.)
  Writing one on our own (setting NAME to ArchiveTar)
  Had problems unarchiving. Please build manually
Skipping test because of notest pragma
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually install a new `Archive::Tar` version first.  It looks like it's trying to use `/bin/tar` to untar the `Archive::Tar` package it downloaded, but failing to do so, perhaps because that's not the correct location of your `tar` binary.

Use `which tar` to find out where `tar` is on your system - it may be `/usr/bin/tar`, in which case, it's looking in the wrong place.

If you're using CPAN.pm for this, you can correct the path to tar with the following from the CPAN.pm shell (which you can get to with `cpan` or `perl -MCPAN -e shell`:

```
o conf tar '/usr/bin/tar'
o conf commit
```

(Using whatever path `which tar` gave you.)

Comment: thank you for your quick reply, i have checked the tar location and it is as above /bin/tar.

How do i manually install a new Archive::Tar

Comment: ok just googled it, http://joysofprogramming.com/install-perl-archive-tar-fedora-rhel/

now when i follow those instructions i get "Package 1:perl-Archive-Tar-1.39.1-1.el5_5.2.noarch already installed and latest version" when i run the instalation

Comment: all sorted thanks for pushing me in the right direction, found the manaul instalation here: http://search.cpan.org/